# Accessing array elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble with writing code that takes a user inputted integer and uses that integer to access that element in the array and gets the sum of the element that the user inputted and the one before and after. For example, if a user inputs 1 I would want to have the element 0+1+2. Please let me know if this information isn't enough and I will try to elaborate more.

Edit:
To add more information, this is the code I have got done already and haven't had any problems with. The problem I am having is coming up with code that will be efficient in completing the task of adding the indexes from the user input. Another example, if the user inputs 8 I would like the program to add the indexes 7+8+9, the number below the user input, user input and above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int user;
        int[] numbers = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 };
        Console.Write("Enter a number from 1 to 8:");
        user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (user > 8 || user < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number.");
        }
        for(int sum)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Always best with these kinds of questions to post your relevant code with it :)

Comment: You've probably elaborated enough...which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: In addition to relevant code, please describe the specific problem you are having. "I am having trouble with not being healthy" would be unacceptably vague at the doctor's office :)

Comment: `Private Sub Test()
        Dim arr As Integer() = {0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 6}
        Dim inp As Integer = 2
        Dim ind As Integer = 0
        Dim result As Integer = 0
        If arr.Contains(inp) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1 Step 1
                If arr(i) = inp Then
                    ind = i
                End If
            Next
        End If
        result = arr(ind - 1) + arr(ind) + arr(ind + 1)
    End Sub`

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the `8` it's better to use the length of the array, or in this case `numbers.Length - 2`. Other than that, you might want to read up on [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure where your `numbers` array is needed at all? your answer would always seem to be `userInput * 3`

Comment: @Sayse Huh? If I enter 1, the sum would be 6. How's that 1 * 3?

Comment: @Sayse userInput = 8, sum = 48 (14 + 16 + 18), userInput % 2 = 0 => userInput % 2 * 3 = 0. What?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - I'm just gonna slowly walk back to my coffee cup.. If that is indeed the correct data used in the `numbers` then  `userInput * 6`

Comment: @Sayse I guess you just wanted to say that `sum = numbers[userInput] * 3` instead of `sum = userInput * 3` :-D

Answer (score 2):

Well, the sum would be:

```
int sum = numbers[user - 1] + numbers[user] + numbers[user+1];
```

Does that answer your question?

---

EDIT You started to write `for (int sum)` which doesn't really make sense. The most efficient way is the above, but you *can* do it with a loop, too:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int idx = -1; i < 2; i++)
    sum = numbers[user + idx];
```

However, that's much harder to understand than the above...

---

EDIT 2 I don't know if the array you provided is the real array you use, but in that case, the answer is even easier:

```
sum = numbers[user] * 3;
```

:-)